# Download canvas chart as PNG image with higher resolution javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

We need to download the canvas chart as png image with higher resolution. tried the below code snippet to resize the image by setting the width and height. but the below solution is giving empty image in download. something failed in below code.

how to resize the canvas chart in downloaded png image.

```
resizeImage(img, w, h) {
    var result = new Image();
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
    result.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    return result;
  }
  downloadChart(event: any, chartName: string) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = (document.getElementsByClassName('chartclassname')[0] as HTMLCanvasElement).toDataURL();  // chartclassname for canvas chart classname
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    var img2 = this.resizeImage(img, 500, 500);
    const anchor = document.getElementById('dynamicDownloadLink') as HTMLAnchorElement;
    anchor.href = img2.src;
    anchor.download = `${this.getChartNameForDownload(chartName)}.png`;
    anchor.click();
  }
```

Comment: I think you need to wait for the `img` laod event before you can call `resizeImage`.

Comment: @Wendelin can you have some sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are creating a new `Image` dynamically you have to wait until it's loaded before you can use it with `drawImage`.

This *should* work:

```
downloadChart(event: any, chartName: string) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = (document.getElementsByClassName('chartclassname')[0] as HTMLCanvasElement).toDataURL();  // chartclassname for canvas chart classname
  img.onload = () => {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    var img2 = this.resizeImage(img, 500, 500);
    const anchor = document.getElementById('dynamicDownloadLink') as HTMLAnchorElement;
    anchor.href = img2.src;
    anchor.download = `${this.getChartNameForDownload(chartName)}.png`;
    anchor.click();
  }
}
```